# vetical-align a line of text in container

Tags: html, css

After reading something on [vertical-align here](https://christopheraue.net/design/vertical-align), i'm decide to do some practice on this feature, but stuck into a problem that really hard to understand. could you please figure out why "the line of text" does not get vertical-aligned in wrapper div.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ctxt {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ctxt-before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f66;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- i think the line-box is 200px and div.ctxt should vertical-aligned in div.wrapper -->
  <div class="ctxt-before"></div>
  <p class="ctxt">this line of text</p>
</div>
```

I think the line-box is 200px and div.ctxt should vertical-aligned in div.wrapper.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got the idea, but you're aligning the middle of the ctxt div with the baseline of the ctxt-before div. Because that has no content, its baseline is its bottom edge.

You need to align it with the middle of the ctxt-before div instead:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ctxt {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ctxt-before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f66;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle; /* add this */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- i think the line-box is 200px and div.ctxt should vertical-aligned in div.wrapper -->
  <div class="ctxt-before"></div>
  <p class="ctxt">this line of text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why you got that result is:

- `div.ctxt-before` is not vertical-aligned in `middle`. By default, `inline or inline-block` element is aligned on `baseline`.
- `div.ctxt-before` does not contain text or image, so the baseline is the bottom of its bounding box. If you try adding text inside `div.ctxt-before`, the text in `p.ctxt` will display at top, because the baseline belongs to text/image, not the bounding box anymore.

If you just want `div.ctxt-before` element and `p.ctxt` element to be vertical-aligned in `middle`, you miss:

```
.ctxt-before{vertical-align: middle;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yours doesn't work because `vertical-align` is for [tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align). When [display modes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model), and [positions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) are considered, it's easy to see that css layout has many aspects. You'll have to read about them to truly understand what's going on.

Try using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), they make this stuff easy:

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.ctxt-before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #f66;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- i think the line-box is 200px and div.ctxt should vertical-aligned in div.wrapper -->
    <div class="ctxt-before"></div>
    <p class="ctxt">this line of text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. there maybe serveral ways to get this work properly, but i'm just want to understand the reason behind this, not the solution.

Comment: there's a bit to it, but the basis is that `vertical-align` is for tables :)

Answer (score -1):

Using flex box you can do this easily.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ssniranga/pen/dqKaNe